# Adding a line of best fit to a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]Hello, this is probably an easy question and I apologize in advance if so.. I am looking to add a line of best fit to these three lines in the graph (ideally a lighter shade of the color that they already are) so that you can see the gradual change in rainfall over time.. would anyone know what to add to this code to achieve this?

My code right now is

```
ggplot(Rain) + 
    geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=Location1,col="red")) + 
    geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=Location2,col="blue")) + 
    geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=Location3,col="green")) + 
    xlab("Time (Days)") + 
    ylab("Rainfall (Inches)") + 
    ggtitle("Rainfall Over 100 Days In Three Locations") + 
    labs(color="Locations") + 
    scale_color_manual(labels = c("Location 1","Location 2","Location 3"), values = c("red","blue","green"))
```

I also need to export it as a high quality TIFF file with dpi=600 if any advice on doing that simply is out there that would be appreciated as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: see `?geom_smooth`

Comment: Also, if you reshape your data to long form (ggplot really likes long form) with `tidyr::pivot_longer` or `gather` whatnot, you can condense all your `geom_line` calls into one.

Comment: ...and to save, call `ggsave()` with a filepath that ends in the extension you want to use, e.g. `ggsave('~/Desktop/my-plot.tiff', dpi = 600)`